pyTube - Downloaded files are not accessible
I've run into a lot of issues with the pyTube package but there have been lots of well documented solutions for the main issues, however I'm not even able to find a reference to this issue.
Both the audio and video files are successfully downloaded however the audio file (length sometimes matches length of the video) has no data. Its just silence. The video file has a message that is the duration of the yt video that just says "The following content is not available on this app. Watch this content on the latest version of YouTube".
Error displayed on video file
My pytube.innertube client is set to ANDROID and these are its params.
    'ANDROID': {
        'innertube_context': {
            'context': {
                'client': {
                    'clientName': 'ANDROID',
                    'clientVersion': '19.08.35',
                    'androidSdkVersion': 30
                }
            },
            "params": "CgIQBg"
        },
        'header': {
            'User-Agent': 'com.google.android.youtube/',
        },
        'api_key': 'AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8'

I assume the clientVersion may be outdated however I'm not able to find any information regarding what the current version would be.
